# Pact-js - Provider/Consumer test missing files in the repository

Tags: node.js, producer-consumer, pact

Hi everyone, 
 I am trying to implement PACT JS.  Currently I am referring to [this implementation](https://github.com/lucasmajerowicz/pact-node-example) :

`npm  install` (or `yarn install`) and the consumer side command (`mocha app/client/spec/PostServiceClient.spec.js`) worked well.The pact file was generated.

But the provider side command (`node app/service/spec/PostService.spec.js`) failed.It's seemed due to the localhost server. But i didn't succeed in running the server. It missed 'THREE' module.

After adding 'THREE' module, i couldn't compile the build. So 2 files are missing in the repository main.js and Template.html (--> `webpack.config.js`).
And i didn't succeed in posting a comment in Lucas M Blog (http://hecodes.com/2016/10/better-testing-microservices-using-consumer-driven-contracts-node-js/)

Could someone help me?
Wilson Mahann

Comment: Try posting code of the attempts so far along with any error messages. If the problem is about a github repository try opening an issue so the repository creator can clear things up.

Comment: Hi Wilson, given you are taking an example project from someone anonymously from the internet, you're best first call is to raise an issue on their repository.

If you like, there are multiple examples on the Pact JS project page to get started, which we can support you with if you had questions.

Comment: Hi Matt, that what i finally decided to do. Thanks a lot to Tristo and you.

Comment: subjet closed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help

*Error messages trying to run the server*

```
 $ yarn server
yarn run v1.9.4
$ webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --config webpack.config.js --devtool eval --progress --hot --inline
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'three'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at Object. (D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\webpack.config.js:34:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at module.exports (D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:80:13)
    at Object. (D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:68:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had successfully the missing module "three" : *yarn add three* 
And run the server

```
$ yarn server
    yarn run v1.9.4
    $ webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --config webpack.config.js --devtool eval --progress --hot --inline
    clean-webpack-plugin: D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\dist has been removed.                                                                                      70% 1/1 build modules
     http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    webpack result is served from /
    content is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                         30% 1/3 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                         44% 4/7 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                         61% 6/7 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       54% 12/16 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       62% 15/17 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       45% 16/27 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       35% 19/44 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       49% 29/44 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       65% 42/45 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       48% 44/69 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       52% 49/69 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       62% 60/69 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       66% 67/71 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                                       69% 75/76 build modulescontent is served from ./app                                                                                                                                  Hash: 2948e04a9d9577c7951d
    Version: webpack 1.15.0
    Time: 569ms
                         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
        bundle.2948e04a9d9577c7951d.js   285 kB       0  [emitted]  app
                            index.html  2.27 kB          [emitted]
        chunk    {0} bundle.2948e04a9d9577c7951d.js (app) 227 kB [rendered]
            [0] multi app 52 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
            [1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 4.16 kB {0} [built]
            [2] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
            [3] ./~/url/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
            [4] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
            [5] ./~/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
            [6] ./~/querystring/index.js 127 bytes {0} [built]
            [7] ./~/querystring/decode.js 2.4 kB {0} [built]
            [8] ./~/querystring/encode.js 2.09 kB {0} [built]
            [9] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
           [10] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
           [11] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 897 bytes {0} [built]
           [12] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
           [13] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport-list.js 613 bytes {0} [built]
           [14] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/websocket.js 2.72 kB {0} [built]
           [15] ./~/process/browser.js 5.42 kB {0} [built]
           [16] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/event.js 2 kB {0} [built]
           [17] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/random.js 746 bytes {0} [built]
           [18] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser-crypto.js 438 bytes {0} [built]
           [19] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/url.js 975 bytes {0} [built]
           [20] ./~/url-parse/index.js 12 kB {0} [built]
           [21] ./~/requires-port/index.js 753 bytes {0} [built]
           [22] ./~/querystringify/index.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
           [23] ./~/debug/src/browser.js 4.73 kB {0} [built]
           [24] ./~/debug/src/debug.js 4.39 kB {0} [built]
           [25] ./~/ms/index.js 2.76 kB {0} [built]
           [26] ./~/inherits/inherits_browser.js 672 bytes {0} [built]
           [27] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js 1.27 kB {0} [built]
           [28] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
           [29] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/websocket.js 210 bytes {0} [built]
           [30] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-streaming.js 1.25 kB {0} [built]
           [31] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/ajax-based.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
           [32] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/sender-receiver.js 1.18 kB {0} [built]
           [33] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/buffered-sender.js 2.3 kB {0} [built]
           [34] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/polling.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
           [35] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/xhr.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
           [36] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-cors.js 343 bytes {0} [built]
           [37] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/abstract-xhr.js 4.8 kB {0} [built]
           [38] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-local.js 352 bytes {0} [built]
           [39] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser.js 560 bytes {0} [built]
           [40] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-streaming.js 984 bytes {0} [built]
           [41] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xdr.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
           [42] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/eventsource.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
           [43] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/eventsource.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
           [44] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/eventsource.js 37 bytes {0} [built]
           [45] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/iframe-wrap.js 981 bytes {0} [built]
           [46] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/iframe.js 3.83 kB {0} [built]
           [47] ./~/json3/lib/json3.js 43.3 kB {0} [built]
           [48] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 43 bytes {0} [built]
           [49] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/version.js 26 bytes {0} [built]
           [50] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/iframe.js 5.04 kB {0} [built]
           [51] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/object.js 532 bytes {0} [built]
           [52] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/htmlfile.js 710 bytes {0} [built]
           [53] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/htmlfile.js 2.2 kB {0} [built]
           [54] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-polling.js 894 bytes {0} [built]
           [55] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-polling.js 712 bytes {0} [built]
           [56] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/jsonp-polling.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
           [57] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/jsonp.js 5.57 kB {0} [built]
           [58] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/jsonp.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
           [59] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/main.js 12 kB {0} [built]
           [60] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/shims.js 17.2 kB {0} [built]
           [61] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/escape.js 2.36 kB {0} [built]
           [62] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/transport.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
           [63] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/log.js 450 bytes {0} [built]
           [64] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/event.js 477 bytes {0} [built]
           [65] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/location.js 178 bytes {0} [built]
           [66] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/close.js 295 bytes {0} [built]
           [67] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/trans-message.js 292 bytes {0} [built]
           [68] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-receiver.js 2.22 kB {0} [built]
           [69] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-fake.js 456 bytes {0} [built]
           [70] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
           [71] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe-receiver.js 791 bytes {0} [built]
           [72] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-ajax.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
           [73] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/iframe-bootstrap.js 2.9 kB {0} [built]
           [74] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/facade.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
           [75] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
           [76] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 813 bytes {0} [built]

    ERROR in multi app
    Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./main.js in D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\app
     @ multi app

    ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
          Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\app\template.html in D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\app:
          Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\app\template.html in D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\app

          - compiler.js:76
            [pact-node-example-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

          - Compiler.js:214 Compiler.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:214:10

          - Compiler.js:403
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:403:12

          - Tapable.js:67 Compiler.next
            [pact-node-example-master]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:67:11

          - CachePlugin.js:40 Compiler.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:40:4

          - Tapable.js:71 Compiler.applyPluginsAsync
            [pact-node-example-master]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:71:13

          - Compiler.js:400 Compiler.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:400:9

          - Compilation.js:577 Compilation.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:577:13

          - Tapable.js:60 Compilation.applyPluginsAsync
            [pact-node-example-master]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:60:69

          - Compilation.js:572 Compilation.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:572:10

          - Tapable.js:60 Compilation.applyPluginsAsync
            [pact-node-example-master]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:60:69

          - Compilation.js:567 Compilation.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:567:9

          - Tapable.js:60 Compilation.applyPluginsAsync
            [pact-node-example-master]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:60:69

          - Compilation.js:563 Compilation.
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:563:8

          - Tapable.js:60 Compilation.applyPluginsAsync
            [pact-node-example-master]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:60:69

          - Compilation.js:525 Compilation.seal
            [pact-node-example-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:525:7


        Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

            ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-master\app\template.html in D:\Workspace\pact-js\js00\pact-node-example-maste
        r\app
    webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Finally, i created *main.js and Template.html* files. And i succeeded in compiling but i dont know what code to implement in my files!!

Thanks a lot